# How to place the output of find in to an array

Tags: shell-script

I am a newbie in Unix. I have a requirement in which I have to put the output of find statement in array because later in the script I have to use the output lines one by one. My find statement will retrieve me the location of directories based on the condition.

Here are the find statements:

```
find blah -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d  -regex ".*/V[0-9]+/wsdls+"
```

Comment: i got a solution for this.. array=($(find blah -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d  -regex ".*/V[0-9]+/wsdls+"))

i=0 
for file in "${array[@]}" do echo "${file}"
let i++
done
but here the strange thing is after executing this though i am able to see data properly but in every line it's saying i++ is not a valida command..and as soon as i removed the i++, then it gave me the data properly..my question is how it is happening as we are not increasing the value of i..

Comment: If you found an answer, please post it as an actual answer and not a comment.

Comment: hard to give you help when we can't see the newlines in your code. Please put it in an answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this:

```
array=( $(find blah -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d -regex ".*/V[0-9]+/wsdls+") )

# loop over it
for i in ${array[@]}
do
    echo $i
done

# or in a while loop
i=0;
while [ $i -lt ${#array[@]} ]
do
    echo $i: ${array[$i]}
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: You'll need to set `IFS=$'\n'` first though: in case any of the filenames have spaces, you want to keep them as a single array element. The you'll also want to use double quotes when referencing the array: `for i in "${array[@]}"`

Comment: This is quite old, but this should have been the accepted answer. It works out quite well, and the comment from @glennjackman is also quite useful.

Comment: A clarification to @glennjackman's answer is that the `IFS=$'\n'` needs to be at the start of the assignment statement, not in the `find` subshell; e.g. `IFS=$'\n' array=(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357277/111036) has all the details and also some alternatives. But essentially, a reliable way to do it is:

```bsh
array=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    array+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find Where What... -print0)
```

Using `-print0` for the output of `find` and a null byte as delimiter for `read` avoids all the pitfalls created by filenames with spaces or worse.

And to iterate over the filenames in the array, use quotes around the array :

```bsh
for file in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```